# How to prevent NullPointerException in my code?

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception

Here's a brief explanation of my program:

1. User keys in data
2. Data is stored in vector
3. User may choose to key in data again...
4. Before the program is closed, a summary screen of data will be displayed.

The problem I'm facing now is that the for loop is executed even before data is stored in it, while what I want is for the for loop to run only summary screen is displayed.

Is there a way to tackle this problem?

SummaryPanel.class (Partial code)

```
    list = new JList<String>();     
    scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    model = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<con.retrievePersonalVector().size(); i++){
        model.addElement(((PersonalRecord)con.retrievePersonalVector().get(i)).getLoginName()); //NPE

    list.setModel(model);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {


        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            int selected = list.getSelectedIndex();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

```
Vector<?> persRecs = con.retrievePersonalVector();
for (int i = 0; i < persRecs.size(); i++) {
    PersonalRecord persRec = (PersonalRecord)persRecs.get(i);
    if (persRec != null) (
        model.addElement(persRec.getLoginName());
    }
}
```

In the original code the retrievePersonalVector was done at every loop step twice: checking the size and getting an element. Instead of 2N times, retrieval is now done once.

Then the model was passed to the component in the loop. Mabye a genuine decision, to see a something, but that probably does not work here, hence I close the loop early. Also adding a listener should be done once. (Or you maybe lost a `}` on copying together the question.

Comment: I've tried your method, but it still doesn't work. `con.retrievePersonalVector` actually returns a vector

Comment: Maybe the returned persRecs is null. The Stacktrace of any exception should tell source, method and line number.

Comment: The NPE is always pointing at `con.retrievePersonalVector();`

Comment: Then `con` must be null, isn't it? It is likely to be a field never (not yet) filled in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use Vector anymore. Prefer `List<T> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>())`.
 Secondly, if the `NullPointerException` is indeed thrown where you spot it, it is probably because the `Vector` contains some null elements, so you should insure that you do not store any null element. Last, why not checking if the summary panel is displayed before looping (either with an `isVisible()` or a local boolean) ?

Comment: In response to your second point, can it be done if I'm using cardlayout?

Comment: I dont think your issue is in any way related to the Layout. As I said in my previous post, your `Vector` might contains some null entries. So when you do `((PersonalRecord)con.retrievePersonalVector().get(i)).getLoginName()`, `((PersonalRecord)con.retrievePersonalVector().get(i))` is null so what your really do is `null.getLoginName()`, resulting in a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yes, I fully understand where the NPE is coming from. The only problem I'm facing right now is preventing the for loop from running.
My vectors will be initially null until the user stores data in it through a gui

Comment: No, your Vector is NOT null. If it was, the exception would be thrown at line `for(int i=0; i<con.retrievePersonalVector().size(); i++)` when calling `size()`. If you cant ensure that your Vector does not contains null values, try to check nullity of the element before using it: `PersonalRecord pr = (PersonalRecord)con.retrievePersonalVector().get(i);` then `if(pr != null) model.addElement(pr.getLoginName());`